# How to fetch dynamically navbar React bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, react-router, fetch, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to fetch a Nav NavItem dynamically, I've been able to fill in, but not dynamically, what I'd like to do is the following, I have on my site, the home page with the latest news, and the sections of Politics, Tech, Business ... to search specifically for each category, but only that the only thing that changes between them is the id of the category, code that I was able to do:

```
CustomNavbar.jsx
    render() {
            return (
                <Navbar default collapseOnSelect>
                    <Navbar.Header>
                        <Navbar.Toggle />
                        <Navbar.Brand>
                            <Link id="Link" to="/">
                                <img src={logo} height="30" alt="logo"/>
                            </Link>
                        </Navbar.Brand>
                    </Navbar.Header>
                    <Navbar.Collapse>
                        <Nav pullRight>
                            <NavItem eventKey={1} componentClass={Link} to="/politics" href="/politics">
                                POLITICS
                            </NavItem>
                            <NavItem eventKey={2} componentClass={Link} to="/business" href="/business" >
                                BUSINESS
                            </NavItem>
                            <NavItem eventKey={3} componentClass={Link} to="/tech" href="tech">
                                TECH
                            </NavItem>
                            <NavItem eventKey={4} componentClass={Link} to="/science" href="science">
                                SCIENCE
                            </NavItem>
                            <NavItem eventKey={5} componentClass={Link} to="/sports" href="sports">
                                SPORTS
                            </NavItem>
                            <NavItem eventKey={6} id="Login" componentClass={Link} to="/login" href="login" >
                                LOGIN
                            </NavItem>
                        </Nav>
                    </Navbar.Collapse>
                </Navbar>
            );
```

I want populate my NavbarItems with something like that:

CustomNavbar.jsx

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            'items': [],
            isLoading: false,
            error: null,
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getItems();
    }

    getItems() {
        this.setState({ 'isLoading': true });

        fetch('xxx/api/category/')
            .then(results => {
                if (results.ok) {
                    return results.json();
                } else {
                    throw new Error('Something went wrong ...');
                }
            })
            .then(results => this.setState({ 'items': results, 'isLoading': false }))
            .catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false }));
    }    


render() {
        return (
            <Navbar default collapseOnSelect>
                <Navbar.Header>
                    <Navbar.Toggle />
                    <Navbar.Brand>
                        <Link id="Link" to="/">
                            <img src={logo} height="30" alt="logo"/>
                        </Link>
                    </Navbar.Brand>
                </Navbar.Header>
                <Navbar.Collapse>
                    <Nav pullRight>
                        {this.state.items.map(function (item, index) {
                            <NavItem eventKey={index} componentClass={Link} 
                             to="/categories/" + {item.name}" href="/categories/" + {item.name}>
                                {item.name}
                            </NavItem>

                         })}


                            LOGIN
                        </NavItem>
                    </Nav>
                </Navbar.Collapse>
            </Navbar>
        );
```

My routes:

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './components/Home/Home';
import Politics from './components/Politics/Politics';
import Business from './components/Business/Business';
import Tech from './components/Tech/Tech';
import Science from './components/Science/Science';
import Sports from './components/Sports/Sports';
import Login from './components/User/Login/Login';
import User from './components/User/User/User';
import Navbar from './components/CustomNavbar/CustomNavbar';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Navbar></Navbar>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
          <Route path="/politics" component={Politics}/>
          <Route path="/business" component={Business}/>
          <Route path="/tech" component={Tech}/>
          <Route path="/science" component={Science}/>
          <Route path="/sports" component={Sports}/>
          <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
          <Route path="/user" component={User}/>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I want to populate these categories as Category, without having to keep repeating code to mount the screen, which I thought of doing, would pass the category value through the URL, but I do not know how to do that in React, any help?

Expected result:

[image]

Folder current structure:

[image]

Folder result structure:

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to fetch the nav bar categories dynamically and then define the routes dynamically?

Comment: Yes, look my last edit, and see if you can help me!! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the post's context visibility, you can create dynamically like this.

**Solution:**
You passed the category name as url parameter and fetch it in the component (in my example, it would be Category).

```
// some import statements

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Navbar />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="categories/:categoryName" component={Category} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
}

// Category component

class Category extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { categoryName } = this.props.match.params;
    return (
      // based on the category name you can render what you want
    )
  }
}
```

The alternative way might be the Higher order component.

Comment: I think that resolves the problem with the routes, look my edit, how I want to populate the Navitem, 
any help for that form? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Are you talking about the CustomNavbar.jsx? I think it is correct. but u should use lamda func / arrow func inside your `map` loop and u should return. Or are . you talking about the routes to generate dynamically ? ?

Comment: I need in routes, I define only one component, for example category, and there in CustomNavbar, I define the URLs and the items of the navbar according to the API return

Comment: So what you should do is make it App component as class component and in componentDidMount fetch those items. Then create those routes as you did in the Navbar. In navbar, dont fetch those again but instead, pass the items from App to Navbar

Comment: Yeah, that way I think works, look at my last edit, with the desired folder structure, for a better understanding of the scenario I'm looking for, in the current form, I'm repeating a lot of code, because I ended up creating a component for each category, but I want to have it as a single category component I believe that understanding will now improve, thankss!!

Comment: Yup, I am glad it helps. Could you please mark this as an answer so that i wouldn't have to return

Comment: Sorry, I have one more question, regarding the dynamic Navitem padding in CustomNavbar, can I use a map function in the list to do this? In which place should I do fetch from the list? In the app.jsx or in the CustomNavbar component?

Comment: Because they are the routes, you should fetch them in app.jsx (a.k.a app container). Padding ? css? you can just do with css in js thing. If you need any of the results, just pass it as a prop.